# WPFToolkit DataGrid Setting value of cell in setter (style)

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have DataGrid and I set:

```
CellStyle="{StaticResource Style}"
```

My style:

```
<Style x:Key="Style" TargetType="{x:Type tool:DataGridCell}" >
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="QWE" />
</Style>
```

But the cells do not have the "qwe" text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Template` and then set the `Content` of the `ContentPresenter`...

```
       <Style x:Key="CenterCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type tool:DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type tool:DataGridCell}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter Content="qwe"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

You could then add an item and the content would show up as *qwe*.

```
        MyDataGrid.Items.Add("");
```